# react router onEnter replace not work

Tags: reactjs, replace, react-router

I wanna use react-router(v3.0.2) onEnter to auth, replace method does not work in first access, but a error thrown. How can i do ?

Landing Page may be protected. (login auth)

```
export default {
    path: '/',
    component: LandingContainer,
    onEnter: (router, replace) => {
        const { store, actions } = context
        const { getState, dispatch } = store
        const state = getState()
        const user = state.get('user')
        if (!user.get('_id')) {
            dispatch(actions.setReturnUrl(location.pathname + 
location.search))
            replace('/login')
            return
        }
        return
    },
    childRoutes: [
        require('./user').default || require('./user'),
        require('./live').default || require('./live'),
        require('./course').default || require('./course')
    ],
    indexRoute: {
        component: Main
    }
}
```

replace not work, but a error occur(only first rendering)

```
warning.js?8a56:33 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `routes` is marked as required in `Root`, but its value is `undefined`.
in Root

warning.js?8a56:33 Warning: Failed child context type: The child context `routes` is marked as required in `Root`, but its value is `undefined`.
in Root
in AppContainer

Warning: [react-router] Location "/" did not match any routes
```

Comment: Are you using React Router v3?

Comment: yes, react-router v3.0.2

Comment: If you're able to use v4 that's highly recommended. What you're trying to do will be a lot easier as well.

Comment: I don't like the style of 4. I think 3 is good enough. I just want to solve the current problem. Is this a bug of v3?